# Azure AD: User account from external identity provider is not supported for application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Here's the situation.  I have 2 Azure AD Directories (in 2 separate tenants), Dir A and Dir B.  I have two separate web applications where one app is registered with Dir A and the other app is registered Dir B.  In my browser, I navigate to the app registered with Dir A and login via Azure AD login page.  That works fine and I'm able access the app.  If I open another tab in my browser and try to navigate to the second app registered with Dir B, I get the following error page:

[image]

I can usually fix this by logging out of the app registered with Dir A (sometimes I need to clear my cache) and then I'm able navigate to the app registered with Dir B and log in successfully.  This doesn't seem right.  Why should I have to logout of a completely separate app registered to a completely separate Azure AD Directory in a separate tenant just so I can access the app registered to Dir B?  When I want to log into Facebook and Twitter using the same browser I don't have to log out of one to access the other.  Seems ridiculous.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: Are you trying to access the two different apps with two different users, or the same one?

Comment: @rich-randall It would be the same physical user with two separate logins.  Pretend that the first web application is walmart.com and is registered to Walmart's Azure AD (Dir A).  The second application is target.com and is registered to Target's Azure AD (Dir B).  The user in this case is both a user of walmart.com and target.com.  The user's login for walmart.com is john.smith@walmart.onmicrosoft.com and his login for target.com is john.smith@target.onmicrosoft.com.